# Repopulate Database with table generated from model

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

A collegue of mine accidentally deleted the UserProfiles table from my database, which was generated from a model class.

Here's what the model class looks like:

```
namespace OneMillion.Models
{
    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string SecretQuestion { get; set; }
        public string SecretQuestionAnswer { get; set; }
        public int MoneyIn { get; set; }
        public int MoneyOut { get; set; }
        public int TimesWon { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I try to Update-Database via the package manager console I get this error:

```
Cannot find the object "dbo.UserProfile" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

Data migrations are enabled.
How can I solve this? Shall I delete the whole database?

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to the DB as a user with sufficient permissions to create databases? You could log in as that user in SSMS and create the table with the appropriate columns etc. Then the table exists, and migrations can find it.